# bash trap is not working for SIGTERM or SIGKILL

Tags: bash, pid, kill, bash-trap

I have this:

```
  trap on_ql_trap EXIT;
  trap on_ql_trap INT;
  trap on_ql_trap TERM;
  echo "pid that called trap: $$"
```

which can probably be turned into shorthand:

```
  trap on_ql_trap EXIT INT TERM;
  echo "pid that called trap: $$"
```

when I kill the process/pid that called trap, using

```
kill <pid>
```

or

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

in the first case, nothing happens. The process lives on. In the second case using -9, the process dies, but the trap is not invoked. So neither kill command is doing what I want! I want the process to exit but I need to trap to be invoked first. Does anyone know why this might be?

Comment: I don't have a good answer for `SIGTERM`, but `SIGKILL` cannot be trapped by any process.

Comment: good point re: SIGKILL

Comment: What makes you think it's not working? What is the content of `on_ql_trap`?

Comment: I tried `kill -2 <pid>` didn't work, but `kill -1 <pid>` did work

Comment: @Patrick I think you are right actually, it probably is working it's just not killing the process, on_ql_trap is not exiting, just removing a folder. You can add an answer if you want will accept.

Comment: actually ughhh it's not trapping a kill <pid> signal...weird

Answer (score 7):

As you have discovered there are two signals that cannot be caught, blocked or ignored. They are `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP`. The reference describing the limitation is [man 7 signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). It spells it out in unambiguous terms:

> ```
> The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or
> ignored.
> ```

That limitation applies to the bash `trap` builtin.